# Creating custom AppDomains in IIS prevents their release, and deadlocks the website

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, iis, iis-7, appdomain

First off, We have written a library, that is used by a Windows Service, and a ASP Webpage that is running in IIS 7.

The library needed to load other libraries as plugins, but some of the external libraries had the same name (but different internal versions). To resolve this binary namespace conflict, we created an AppDomain for each plugin. The Library has a Manager object which references a pool of static connections. Inside the pool of static SharedConnections, the AppDomains live and are destroyed. When the last Manager objects is removed, the Manager object invokes the cleanup of the SharedConnections. This cleanup releases the AppDomains we created.

The Service that relies on our library handles this beautifully. At the beginning of its lifetime it creates the AppDomains and at the conclusion it removes them during cleanup.

The Website that relies on our library handles this poorly. At the beginning of its lifetime it creates the AppDomains, however when IIS decides to unload us after a period of inactivity, the Manger objects are deleted, which invokes the cleanup of the SharedConnection objects as expected. Which in turn kills off the AppDomains.

There are two problems

a) We use `lock()` around the connection and AppDomain releases, so they don't release twice and subsequently throw errors. Except for some reason, on rare instances, the thread that enters the lock and kills the AppDomain ceases to exist, and never leaves the lock, causing a dead lock scenario. The only way we can resolve this is to stop the AppPool in IIS and restart it 30-60 seconds later. This does not happen with the Windows Service.

b) When we don't observe the above scenario (which is rarely happens), instead occasionally we have AppDomain release issues, this throws Exceptions that crash and restart the webpage, which is okay-ish.

Other things I have discovered via debug. IIS places the website in its own AppDomain, which means we are a child AppDomain making more child AppDomains.

What are we doing wrong? Is there an IIS configuration that might help?

Comment: What kind of exceptions get thrown when you encounter problem b?

Comment: `System.ArgumentException: Invalid token for impersonation - it cannot be duplicated.` Followed by a `CarmineException` claiming insufficient privileges.

This is caused because we are making a connection to SCVMM. However I've dumped the credentials on this fault, and they are the correct credentials.

I believe this is happening after a recycle of the IIS AppPool (due to inactivity), The result is we can't correctly re-enable our own AppDomains.

Comment: Instead, why don't you setup different websites in IIS for each binary version & IIS will manage AppDomains correctly. Setup a cookie to identify version & use Routing to select website. ARP will do the routing and everything will be managed well by IIS.

Comment: @AkashKava we will be trying your method soon. Toss in an answer if you would if your solution works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Application Request Routing**

To solve exact same problem, IIS created ARR to route request to specific version of application based on URL, Cookie or Header parameter which is configurable easily. ARR works as a HTTP Proxy server, which does simple routing.

Here is the example,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2010/04/02/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx

IIS will do its job of recycling and managing application pools and managing domains for you, you don't have to do any of that.

Comment: While this wasn't exactly what I did, I ended up creating a WCF service for each one separately and let (as you said) IIS's app pools do it job and I didn't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to avoid problem a) by putting your SharedConnection and AppDomain clean up code in the [destructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) of your Manager object. The destructor will be invoked exactly once by the garbage collector after the manager is disposed and no longer referenced, or when the AppDomain containing the Manager is unloaded. That should eliminate the risk of having your clean up thread aborted by IIS. (This may count as an abuse of the destructor functionality, but I'm not sure what the negative consequences, if any, might be.)

Comment: This effectively happens, but because we spawn so many Manager objects (one for each client connection) we have them share connections to other resources such as the AppDomains and SQL Connection pools and more... The problem is when the Shared connections terminate. (maybe we could do similar things around shared connections?)

Comment: @ohmusama, when you say "effectively happens" what do you mean? The important part about using putting your code in the destructor is that the destructor is run on the GC's thread, which I'm pretty sure IIS won't abort unexpectedly.